# Generating grammar for the given language

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

Can someone please give a couple of examples of the language and construct a grammar for the language (given below), or at least show me how I can go about it?

I am looking for a context-free grammar generating the language

$$ L = \{ a^n b^m \mid n,m \geq 0 \text{ and } n \neq 2m \}. $$

I asked a similar question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15559324/6524169), where it was closed.

After seeing that question one thing is very clear to me:

1. Take care of the case when $n<2m$ (as in the stackoverflow question).
2. Take care of the case when $n>2m$ (not sure how to do that).

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: I am gaining understanding as this wasn't any homework...I was trying to solve the questions in the book Formal Automata by Peter Linz..

Comment: Moreover not everyone has excess to elite class professors who help there students...atleast in my case it isn't

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/141834/755

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G = (\{S\}, \{A, B\}, P, S)$ the formal grammar which production rules $P$ are: 
$S \to aaSb \mid A \mid B \mid aB$ 
$A \to aA \mid a$ 
$B \to Bb \mid b$

We have $L(G) = L$.

### Explanation:

- $n < m$ : The $a$'s are generated in $S$. Whenever the count is right, the remaining $b$ are generated in $B$. If $n$ is odd, the production rule $S \to aB$ is used.
- $m < n < 2m$ : Same as above.
- $n = 2m$ : The only way to generate such a word is in $S$; if you branched to either $A$ or $B$, the hypothesis wouldn't hold anymore as you would  prepend (*resp.* append) at least one $a$ (*resp.* $b$). As this symbol is nonterminal, this class of words isn't accepted.
- $n > 2m$ : The $b$'s are generated in $S$, and the remaining $a$'s are generated in $A$.

Comment: Please consider not to encourage [undesirable posting behaviour](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594).